# Fecthing data from two different tables located in different databased and having relation by primary and foreign key

Tags: hibernate, sessionfactory

### Im using two database in mysql Database lets say **DB1** and **DB2** I configured both the databases in seperate `.cfg.xml` file Now Some of the tables from DB1 are linked to tables in **DB2** for example `DB1.Branch.Branchid` is primary key referes to foreigh key to `DB2.OfficeAddress.Branchidf` In HQL query I want to access the the details of `DB1.Branch` using the `DB@.Lesseemaster.Branchid` to execute the query which database sessionfactory need to use ? Totally confused Im not getting any reference , can we map the data from related tables located in different databases in Hibernate.

> hibernate.cgf.xml

```
    <hibernate-configuration>           
            <session-factory >  
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
                <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
                <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vrfdb</property>  
                <property name="connection.username">root</property>  
                <property name="connection.password"></property>  
                <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
                <property name="show_sql">true</property>
                <property name="format_sql">true</property>  
                <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>           
                <mapping class="LA_DAO.OwnerDAO"/>
                <mapping class="LA_DAO.PropertyDAO"/>           
                <mapping class="LA_DAO.ActivityDAO"/>
                <mapping class="LA_DAO.LesseeDAO"/>


         </session-factory>
        </hibernate-configuration>
```

<< hibernate1.cgf.xml>>

```
    <hibernate-configuration>              
                <session-factory>  
     <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
                <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306   /leavemanagement</property>  
                <property name="connection.username">root</property>  
                <property name="connection.password"></property>  
                <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
                <property name="show_sql">true</property>
                <property name="format_sql">true</property>  
                <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

                <mapping class="LA_DAO.BranchDAO"/>             

             </session-factory>
   </hibernate-configuration>
```

```
    package LA_DAO;  
    @Entity
@Table(name = "branchmaster" )
public class BranchDAO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "branch_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "branch_type_code")
    private int br_main_id;

    @Column(name = "branch_name")
    private String branchName;

    @Column(name = "branch_code")
    private String branchCode;

//getters n setters
}
```

<> 
    package LA_DAO;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lessee_master")
public class LesseeDAO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int lesseeId;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String LesseeName;

    @Column(name ="Address")
    private String LesseeAddress;

    @Column(name = "ContactNumber")
    private String LesseeNumber;

    @Column(name ="EmailID" )
    private String LesseeEmail;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER  )
    @JoinColumn(name = "BranchId")
    private BranchDAO branch;

}
```

Comment: You can create a dbLink in say DB1 refering the table on DB2 and then create a view say VW on DB1 querying this dbLink. Now you can create any type of relationship among your primary table of DB1 and newly created view VW in hibernate.

Comment: thank you so much Avis..Its working fine now:)